# How to solve this parametric logarithmic limit of sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Trying to figure out how to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{ln(n^a+1)}{ln (n)} , with \ a \ \in \Re $$

This is what I tried so far:

$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{ln(n^a+1)}{ln (n)} = \lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{ln(n^a(1 + \frac{1}{n^a}))}{ln (n)} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{ln (n^a) + ln(1+ \frac{1}{n^a})}{ln(n)} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{ln(n^a)}{ln(n)} + \frac{ln(1+ \frac{1}{n^a})}{ln(n)}$

But don't know how to go further.

Comment: Is here supposed to be $$a>0$$?

Comment: Nope, i should study the limit by a variations (what if a > 0, or a < 0 etc..)

Comment: Recall that $\ln(x^a)=a \ln(x)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For $a>0$ we get
$$\frac{a\ln(n)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^a}\right)}{\ln(n)}$$
and for $$a<0$$ write
$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{n^{-a}+1}\right)}{\ln(n)}$$

Comment: So for $a>0$ I get $$ \frac{aln(n)}{ln(n)} + \frac{ln(1 + \frac{1}{n^a})}{ln(n)} = a + \frac{ln(1+\frac{1}{n^a})}{ln(n)} $$ but how do I proceed from that? Also thanks everybody for answers :)

Comment: $$\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^a}\right)}{\ln(n)}$$ tends to zero for $n$ tends to infinity

Comment: If $a>0$ is given

Comment: Great, thank you!